# Converting a class into const stateless function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello below I have a class that doesn't use any life-cycle methods or states, I have read documentation about converting such classes into consts. however, I'm not sure how I seem to struggle with the below class:

```
class ContractsTableHead extends Component {
  createSortHandler(property) {
    return event => {
      this.props.onRequestSort(event, property);
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { order, orderBy } = this.props;
    return (
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          {rows.map(
            row => (
              <TableCell
                key={row.id}
                align={row.numeric ? "right" : "left"}
                padding={row.disablePadding ? "none" : "default"}
                sortDirection={orderBy === row.id ? order : false}
              >
                <Tooltip
                  title="Sort"
                  placement={row.numeric ? "bottom-end" : "bottom-start"}
                  enterDelay={300}
                >
                  <TableSortLabel
                    active={orderBy === row.id}
                    direction={order}
                    onClick={this.createSortHandler(row.id)}
                  >
                    {row.label}
                  </TableSortLabel>
                </Tooltip>
              </TableCell>
            ),
            this
          )}
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
    );
  }
}

ContractsTableHead.propTypes = {
  onRequestSort: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  order: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  orderBy: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  rowCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired
};

export default ContractsTableHead;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make the class component into a function component, you need to make your method `createSortHandler` into a regular function as well:

```
const ContractsTableHead = props => {
  const createSortHandler = property => {
    return event => {
      props.onRequestSort(event, property);
    };
  };
  const { order, orderBy } = props;

  return (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        {rows.map(row => (
          <TableCell
            key={row.id}
            align={row.numeric ? "right" : "left"}
            padding={row.disablePadding ? "none" : "default"}
            sortDirection={orderBy === row.id ? order : false}
          >
            <Tooltip
              title="Sort"
              placement={row.numeric ? "bottom-end" : "bottom-start"}
              enterDelay={300}
            >
              <TableSortLabel
                active={orderBy === row.id}
                direction={order}
                onClick={createSortHandler(row.id)}
              >
                {row.label}
              </TableSortLabel>
            </Tooltip>
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  );
};
```